# can't open file : [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tpu

```
seohyun3545@tpu-vm:~$ python3 tomato.py
```

> python3: can't open file '/home/seohyun3545/tomato.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I cannot run python on the cloud shell. Since I used pwd to check current directory, I'm sure that 'tomato.py' is in the same directory('/home/seohyun3545'). How can I solve this problem?

I guess it's related with TPU because there was nothing wrong when I didn't connect to TPU.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAhfP.png).com/zMzvj.png)

Comment: `pwd` is giving you the current directory. That's where the command will look for `tomato.py`, i.e., it will always look for that file in the current directory, and thus it will look for a file called `/home/seohyun3545/tomato.py`. And it can not find that file. This implies that `tomato.py` is not in `/home/seohyun3545`. You can check the contents of the directory using the `ls` command. That'll show what files are stored in `/home/seohyun3545/` and I expect `tomato.py` will not be among them.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be TPU related issue.

You could try two ways below to see if `tomato.py` is in this current directory:

1. Run `ls -lh`, and see if `tomato.py` is there.
2. Run `test -f tomato.py; echo $?`. If it returns code 1, that means `tomato.py` file does not exist.